# How not to call initialize at each request with Tornado

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I want to set variables when starting my Tornado webserver, so I tried to override `initialize` on my `RequestHandler` class. But apparently, `initialize` is launched each time a request is made, according to the following code and its output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self):
        print("Launching initialization...")

    def get(self):
        print("Get: {}{}".format(self.request.host, self.request.uri))

app = tornado.web.Application([=
    (r"/.*", MainHandler)
])

def runserver():
    import tornado.ioloop

    app.listen(8080)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    runserver()
```

stdout:

```
~ ➤ ./redirector.py
Launching initialization...
Get: 127.0.0.1:8080/
Launching initialization...
Get: 127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico
Launching initialization...
Get: 127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico
Launching initialization...
Get: 127.0.0.1:8080/
```

This behavior is the complete contrary to what is written in the [doc](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.initialize):

> Hook for subclass initialization.

(Meaning it is called at the end of `__init__`)

So, does anybody know how to do what I want to ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not contrary to the doc; have a look at the [Structure of a Tornado app](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/structure.html) section. A `RequestHandler` object is created for each request.

If you want code to be executed when the app is started only, subclass the `Application` class and override `__init__`, or just put it in your runserver function.